# Multiple rapid updates to a single resource getting collapsed into a single latest version

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I was trying to create a kubernetes CRD to manage some of the resources on our system
But I noticed that in case the CROs for this CRD are operated on rapidly (delete after create, multiple updates, update after create etc) they get collapsed into a single latest version (I am not sure at what point in the kubernetes infra is this done).

Is is possible to disable such collapsing of CRO operations?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? Exactly what operations are you performing, and what observer os seeing things get collapsed, and how are they watching/detecting that collapse?

Comment: For example, to test the system, I created a 100 CROs in quick succession. I need that for each kubectl command that I issue (which will commit the config to etcd), a single informer trigger happens. Instead I see through my logging infrastructure that the commits for multiple CROs happened before the informer was triggered for the first one.